# Handling data in UITableViews Or the rightapproach in doin this

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a object called test which has many properties . Now my RootViewController has a 
table, which is filled with Array1.(Array1 contain testObject) .Array1 is filled when user 
adds objects.  Now when I click on each of the cells, I open  ViewController 2. Now here in
ViewController 2 , I have an array called Array2 which is an [array of arrays]. So, its 
like firstView is folders and secondView is about the items inside folders. Array2 is also
filled with same testObject whenever the user adds.

Now I am using local notification to set reminders on these items inside the folders, and for all the reminders set by the user,I place all the items in another array called AlarmArray, and when the local notification pops up , I open anotherViewController  called AlarmViewcontroller and show the items which have alarm set. In this AlarmViewcontroller, the items can be from any folder. Now when AlarmViewcontroller  is opened , user may delete the cell.

Now here is the problem, when the user deletes the item from AlarmViewController, it should get deleted from the Viewcontroller2 also.Here I am not understanding , how to do this process, because the item can be from any folder, and their can be items with same name.

Comment: Please add spaces to your questions, This is not a place to write story.

Comment: I would be happy to help you, but you question is not clear. Can you please rephrase it? Thanks!

Comment: @carbonr, I have added spaces, can you help me out

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationNamed:@"deleteReminder" withObject:strMyReminderName];
```

Add an observer for this notification in your ViewController2 with a callback method to delete the reminder from ViewController2:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver....];

-(void)deleteReminderCallback:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSString *strReminderName = [notification object];

   // use strReminderName to target and delete the correct reminder
}
```

Comment: Hi, Zhang,  I have a protocol method, in my customcell.h that does deleting of the cell in ViewController 1 and 2. Now, you say that I have to create oneMoreFunction, with the sane code